# What set is this? (Z \ {0})

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm not sure what this set would look like. Integers divided by the set of 0? Is it Z over {0} or {0} over Z?

Comment: $$A\setminus B=\{x\mid x\in A,\,x\notin B\}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple, the set of integers without zero. $\mathbb{Z}-\{0\}=\{....,-2,-1,1,2,....\}$